# Can I copy the "node_modules" directory to other machines without having to run "npm install" each time?

Tags: node.js, npm

Two Linux machines.  Both are CentOS x64, but different versions.

Say I run `npm install` on machine #1, copy my entire application including the `node_modules` directory to machine #2 and run it there.  Is that supported? Or, it is always advised to run `npm install` on each machine?

I was successful doing `npm install` on a Centos 6 x64 machine, copying the app including `node_modules` to a Centos 7 x64 machine.  The application seemed to run fine.  Even though it worked for me, is this generally safe to do so?

Answer (score 9):

> Is it always advised to run npm install on each machine?

Probably so, because that is one of the purposes of a package manager, to maintain your packages easily across machines.

That being said, nothing is stopping you from directly copying `node_modules` somewhere else. In fact, this might be necessary in the case that you want to add your project to a machine that is offline. Technically, you could even copy them to a machine that doesn't even have `npm`. From node's perspective, if the `node_modules` is there, it will find its dependencies.

> Is this generally safe to do so?

Well, the security issue isn't really in copying `node_modules` versus re-installing them. The more important issue is to understand the security implications of all of your dependencies and, when confirming they are safe, to lock them to specific versions in `package.json`. That way you'll make sure that every `npm install` installs the same code* (assuming `npm` itself isn't doing something funky but that's always a trust problem)

*Even if you fix versions in your `package.json` file, there's still possible breaks that can happen. For example, a dependency of a project you depend on with a specific version itself depends on another package with a version range.
This means that, technically, authors of those other packages can add code that no longer supports your version of node or introduce a bug or fix a bug that you actually depend on etc.

If you know your dependencies are safe and you 100% want to leave them that way, copy the `node_modules` folder and disconnect from the internet :)

Here's a good related read on [general state of software dependencies today](https://research.swtch.com/deps) and [another one with more NPM details](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/immutable-npm-dependencies).

Comment: What about node_modules from a linux machine to windows machine? Then run npm rebuild? Think this would work?

Comment: Assuming the node version is the same, in theory it should work.